# URL issue with route setting

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

```
$route['allgrant'] = "grant/allgrant";
```

The above is working fine for the URL: http://localhost/grant/allgrant

But I am getting error with URL http://localhost/grant/allgrant/6

My route setting is below:

```
$route['allgrant/(:num)'] = "grant/allgrant/$1";
```

My controller code:

```
public function allGrant()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url('allGrant');
    $config['total_rows'] =   $this->db->count_all("grant_data");
    $config['per_page'] = 3;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $data["allGrant"] = $this->grant_model->allGrant($config["per_page"], $page);
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['mainContent'] = 'viewGrant';
    $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
}
```

when I load the all grant page it show me the first three result but when I click on the pagination it give error with page not found

Answer (score 1):

Try this one add this route in your file

```
$route['grant/allgrant/(:num)'] = "grant/allgrant/$1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from

```
$route['allgrant/(:num)'] = "grant/allgrant/$1";
```

To

```
$route['allgrant/(:any)'] = "grant/allgrant/$1";
```

Comment: tried this no luck still getting error page not found

Comment: @Ricky what is in you `controller`?

Comment: public function allGrant()
 {
  $this->load->library('pagination');
  $config = array();
  $config["base_url"] = base_url('allGrant');
  $config['total_rows'] =   $this->db->count_all("grant_data");
  $config['per_page'] = 3;
  $config["uri_segment"] = 2;
  
 }

Comment: @Ricky please update you question with your controller code

Comment: http://localhost/grant/grant/allgrant/6 when I try this it work for me .Grant is my controller name I don not want controller name in the url.

Comment: @Ricky Why there is `grant/grant` two times in your provide url?

Comment: One grant is my codeiginter name and second grant is my controller name

Answer (score 0):

Settings missing with .htaccess, and it is not able to parse the last parameter in URL

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+) index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: this is my .htaccess file